# Is there a standard for air temperature within an aircraft?

Tags: air-travel

On my recent flight to Tokyo on UA I found the cabin immensely cold and not only did I ask for an extra blanket, I also asked if the temperature could be raised. The flight attendant did not refuse and actually said she would check - and probably did something - because I did feel better after a while (unless I just got used to the cooler temperature). However on my return flight it was just the opposite and the flight was extremely warm. 
So I'm wondering, is there not an FAA standard for in-flight temperature (and probably pressure) or it is fairly arbitrary - within a range, of course?

Comment: there are two: scalding hot and freezing cold.

Comment: This is covered in the older question. An airline may have a standard for cabin temperature— European airlines are anecdotally but widely reported to prefer much warmer cabins than American ones— but it is ultimately down to the flight crew, and in some cases depending on the aircraft type, the section of the aircraft and the flight crew working that section. [A recently proposed range](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/2008-10-05/travel/0810010065_1_cold-temperature-heat) for recommended cabin temperatures is 65°F/18°C to 85°F/29°C, which is a pretty wide range by any standard.

Comment: @choster after more than a decade working in planes, I can tell you that most cabin temperature thermostat systems are screwed and you can set the temperature target to 21C but reality could be 18C or 26C...